# Ionic 6 - Viewchild null in dynamic component loader

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, viewchild, angular13, ionic6

I´m developing an Ionic application that will have a form with controls created dinamically from JSON data.

load-child.directive.ts:

```js
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamicChild]'
})
export class DynamicChildLoaderDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```js
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DynamicChildLoaderDirective],
...
```

home.page.html

```html
...
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">
  
    <form [formGroup]="testForm">
      <ion-card *ngFor="let objGrupo of grupos">
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>{{objGrupo.label}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        
        <ion-card-content *ngFor="let objControl of objGrupo.controls">
          <app-dynamic-form [control]="objControl" [form]="testForm"></app-dynamic-form>
        </ion-card-content>    
      </ion-card>
      
    </form>
</ion-content>
...
```

home.page.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DynamicFormGroup } from '../models/dynamic_form_group';
import { Ticket } from '../models/ticket';
import { TicketService } from '../services/ticket.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  grupos: DynamicFormGroup[] = [];
  testControl: any = {};
  testForm: FormGroup;
  validation_messages: any;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder,private ticketService: TicketService) {

    this.ticketService.obtenerFormularioTicket()
      .subscribe(obtainedInfo => {
        var ticket: Ticket = obtainedInfo;
        this.grupos = ticket.getFormList();
        this.testControl = this.grupos[0].controls;
      });
  }

}
```

dynamic-form.component.html:

```html
<ion-label>{{ control.Name }}</ion-label>  

<ng-template dynamicChild></ng-template>
```

dynamic-form.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Type, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DynamicChildLoaderDirective } from 'src/app/directives/load-child.directive';
import { DnElement } from '../dn-element/dn-element.component';
import { DnInputTextComponent } from '../dn-input-text/dn-input-text.component';
import { DnLabelComponent } from '../dn-label/dn-label.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.scss'],
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DynamicChildLoaderDirective, { static: true }) dynamicChild!: DynamicChildLoaderDirective;
  @Input() control: any;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  componente: Type<any>;  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadDynamicComponent();
  }

  private loadDynamicComponent() {
    if(!this.control.Editable){
      this.componente = DnLabelComponent;
    }else{
      this.componente = DnInputTextComponent;
    }  
    const componentRef = this.dynamicChild.viewContainerRef.createComponent<DnElement>(this.componente);
    componentRef.instance.objControl = this.control;
    componentRef.instance.form = this.form;
  }
}
```

The problem is when running the application, the line

```js
const componentRef = this.dynamicChild.viewContainerRef.createComponent<DnElement>(this.componente);
```

returns the following error:

```js
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.dynamicChild is undefined
```

I´m using the following versions:

Ionic Version: 6.1.5

Angular Version: 13.3.5

I´m Using the offical angular docs as guide:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

I´ve tried to change the static property of the ViewChild to false and move the ngOnInit to the ngAfterViewInit with the same result.

Is there anything missing here?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I´ve also tried with viewChildren:

```js
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DynamicChildLoaderDirective, { static: true }) dynamicChild!: DynamicChildLoaderDirective;
  @ViewChildren(DynamicChildLoaderDirective) viewChildren!: QueryList<DynamicChildLoaderDirective>;
  @Input() control: any;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  componente: Type<any>;  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    //this.loadDynamicComponent();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // viewChildren is set
    this.viewChildren.changes.subscribe((r) => {
      console.log(this.viewChildren);
    });

  }
```

No error presents but it never enters the console.log part of the subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to get it work. The code is ok as is, with the difference that the declaration of the directive has to be done in the page in which I´m using it. In this case in **home.module.ts** instead of app.module.ts:

```js
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage,DynamicFormComponent,DynamicChildLoaderDirective]
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call template references when your page fully loaded and for that We have a lifecycle hooks triggered when your page fully loaded:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.loadDynamicComponent();
}
```

Comment: As I stated, I´ve tried that, with the same result. I´ve also tried the combination ngAfterViewInit and static: true, and as the docs says, with static: true it´s should be available on ngOnInit

Comment: remove static true object

Comment: @ViewChild(DynamicChildLoaderDirective) dynamicChild!: DynamicChildLoaderDirective;

Comment: then call your script  inside ngAfterViewInit

Comment: I obtain the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ngAfterContentInit(){
  this.loadDynamicComponent();
}
```

Comment: I get the same result as with ngAfterViewInit